# Django thumbnails, simple

Tags: django, thumbnails

I have a folder with static content, site_media. It is served using django.views.static.serve

```
#settings.py:
STATIC_DOC_ROOT = 'site_media/'
```

and

```
#urls.py:
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (...)
    url(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', 
        {'document_root': settings.STATIC_DOC_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True})
)
```

Now, I just want to show smaller versions of these pictures on my site. I was hoping that there was an app with a template tag that could easily do this.

I am dreaming about smth like:
  {% img "/site_media/foo.png" "100x100" %}

Which would create a resized picture somewhere in site_media, and then return the url for that, which could be "site_media/resized/foo_100x100.png".

I have been looking at Sorl-Thumbnail, but honestly I don't really understand how it operates. Sorry if I missed it, but it looks to me as if they never explain the flow from http request to response. And I am also not sure if Sorl even suits my problem.

Comment: Hi @Lucy. Sorl's thumbnail tag will do exactly what you want. It's pretty simple to implement: http://thumbnail.sorl.net/template.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such a thing. I normally use something based on this custom template filter:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/955/

Comment: So what you mean is that, there is _no_ such thing (as a downloadable module), but I should build it myself?

Comment: I don't know any app that you just add. But if you download the snippet I posted, put it in a folder in your app called templatetags (with an __init__.py file), and then use {% load %} in your template you can easily generate thumbnails:

<img src="{{ object.image|thumbnail:200x300 }}" alt="image resized to 200x300">